# Why "/" and "/boot/efi" belongs to different filesystem

Tags: filesystems

version : CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111

[image]

In this picture,
"/"belongs to "/dev/vda3" filesystem and "/boot/efi" belongs to "/dev/vda2" filesystem.
On my opinion,"/" contains "/boot/efi".
So,why are they belongs to different filesystem??
That really confused me a long time .
Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all `/dev/vda2` and `/dev/vda3` are block devices (partitions on `/dev/vda` disk) not filesystems. These are formatted with a filesystem (most likely XFS in case of `/dev/vda3` and FAT in case of `/dev/vda2`).

Both `/` and `/boot/efi` are [mount points](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=mounting-mount-points) -- directories where filesystems are mounted.

When you [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) a filesystem to a directory you are saying "make content of this filesystem available here". So content of `/dev/vda3` is available in `/`. This means both files and directories and their content. But any directory under `/` can be also a mount point with a filesystem mounted there -- so `/` contains `/boot/efi` but it is just an empty directory that is used as a mount point for `/dev/vda2` which actually contains the content you see inside `/boot/efi`.

Placing different directories in the [filesystem hierarchy](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/) on different devices is pretty common. Sometimes it is just a convenience thing (placing `/home` on a separate partition makes reinstalling easier) and sometimes it is necessity -- `/boot/efi` must be a FAT filesystem so it must be a separate [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition).